# Remove options from command

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression, options

My inputs are commands followed by an unrestricted number of single-letter options, e.g. `command -abc`. Neither the command nor the options take any arguments. My goal is to remove certain options.

Removing options `b` and `c` as an example, I can achieve this like this:

```
$ cmd='command -abc'
$ pattern='(.*) -(.*)'
$ [[ $cmd =~ $pattern ]]
$ echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]} -${BASH_REMATCH[2]//[cb]}"
command -a
```

However, this only works in bash. How can I solve this problem in a compatible way, e.g. using `sed` and `grep` ?

Comment: What is known about the command? Do you know all its options and what options takes arguments?

Comment: Another way to put it: In your example, `command -abc`, how do you know it isn't a single option `-a` with an option-argument `bc` (or `-a -b c`, i.e. `-b` takes an option-argument)? And what happens with `command -abc -d -- -abc`? With real command line parsing, removing `-b` and `-c`, that should probably become `command -a -d -- -abc`, assuming `-a` takes no argument, and regardless of whether `-b` takes an argument or not, right? If `-a` takes an argument, the command line options should remain unchanged, right?

Comment: @Kusalananda there are no arguments/option-arguments for the command, only single-letter options. In case there are no options the input is `command --`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the command only takes single letter options, and that none of the options takes an argument, we may create a wrapping script that parses the command line options, remove the unwanted options and executes the command given the new set of options:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

savedopts=-

printf 'Args in  = %s\n' "$*"

while getopts :bc opt; do
        case $opt in
                b|c) ;; # nothing
                *)
                        savedopts="$savedopts$OPTARG"
        esac
done

shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"

set -- "$savedopts" -- "$@"

printf 'Args out = %s\n' "$*"

# Run the command:

some-command "$@"
```

This parses the command line, ignores the options `b` and `c`, and puts the rest of the options into `$savedopts`.

`$savedopts` is then used to run the wrapped command, together with any operands given on the original command line (separated with `--`).

We don't get any errors from `getopts` even though we ask it to parse options that it may not expect.  This is due to the initial `:` in the first argument to `getopts`.

Test run:

```bash
$ ./script -abcd -b -c -- -bx -a foo bar
Args in  = -abcd -b -c -- -bx -a foo bar
Args out = -ad -- -bx -a foo bar
./script: some-command: not found
```

Comment: Thank you, this works very well! However, this seems overly complex for a simple problem. Except for when there are no options, the input always has exactly one `-`, followed by the letters. Is there no simple `sed` one-liner that behaves exactly like the code I put in my question?